# Importing DLL into Python 3 without imp.load_dynamic

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, dll

### Goal

I am trying to add Windows support for [Python Interface to Total Phase Aardvark](https://github.com/kontron/python-aardvark) that is currently Linux only .  This is a wrapper for a device whose available interface is only a .so (Linux) or .dll (Windows) closed source binary.  However, it was made as a Python package (not sure if that is the right term) rather than just standard C interface that your would load with ctypes.

### File Structure

In this project, we have an ext folder that is the same level as the script doing the importing, with 32/64 libraries for Linux and Windows (added by me):

```
pyaardvark.py (file doing imports)
ext
  linux32
    __init.py__ (empty)
    aardvark.so
  linux 64
    __init.py__ (empty)
    aardvark.so
  win32
    __init.py__ (empty)
    aardvark.dll
  win64
    __init.py__ (empty)
    aardvark.dll
```

### Import Issues

Linux implementation uses:

```
from .ext.linux32 import aardvark as api
```

I initially testing adding the windows import in Python 2.7 and was unable to get the relative path style import to work.  The only method I was successful with is the following:

```
import imp
import os
cur_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
api = imp.load_dynamic('aardvark', os.path.join(cur_path, 'ext', 'win32', 'aardvark.dll'))
```

This seems ugly, but works fine with Python 2.7 and all of the api is available.

I toggle over to Python 3.4 to test there and see that imp is deprecated.  Not only that, it doesn't look like imp had load_dynamic in Python 3 from 3.2 on.  I cannot find a way in Python 3.4 to make this DLL available.

### Attempts

#### Method 1

Fails in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4

```
from .ext.win32 import aardvark as api
```

#### Method 2

Fails in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4

```
import importlib
import os
cur_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
api = importlib.import_module('aardvark', os.path.join(cur_path, 'ext', 'win32', 'aardvark.dll'))
```

#### Method 3

Works in Python 2.7, fails in Python 3.4

```
import imp
import os
cur_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
api = imp.load_dynamic('aardvark', os.path.join(cur_path, 'ext', 'win32', 'aardvark.dll'))
```

#### Method 4

Doesn't throw an error in Python 2.7 or Python 3.4, but not what I'm looking for

```
import os
cur_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
from ctypes import cdll
api = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(cur_path, 'ext', 'win32', 'aardvark.dll'))
```

With working (imp.load_dynamic) import in Python 2.7, `dir(api)` gives me:

`['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'py_aa_async_poll', 'py_aa_close', 'py_aa_configure', 'py_aa_features', 'py_aa_find_devices', 'py_aa_find_devices_ext', 'py_aa_gpio_change', 'py_aa_gpio_direction', 'py_aa_gpio_get', 'py_aa_gpio_pullup', 'py_aa_gpio_set', 'py_aa_i2c_bitrate', 'py_aa_i2c_bus_timeout', 'py_aa_i2c_free_bus', 'py_aa_i2c_monitor_disable', 'py_aa_i2c_monitor_enable', 'py_aa_i2c_monitor_read', 'py_aa_i2c_pullup', 'py_aa_i2c_read', 'py_aa_i2c_read_ext', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_disable', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_enable', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_read', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_read_ext', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_set_response', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_write_stats', 'py_aa_i2c_slave_write_stats_ext', 'py_aa_i2c_write', 'py_aa_i2c_write_ext', 'py_aa_i2c_write_read', 'py_aa_log', 'py_aa_open', 'py_aa_open_ext', 'py_aa_port', 'py_aa_sleep_ms', 'py_aa_spi_bitrate', 'py_aa_spi_configure', 'py_aa_spi_master_ss_polarity', 'py_aa_spi_slave_disable', 'py_aa_spi_slave_enable', 'py_aa_spi_slave_read', 'py_aa_spi_slave_set_response', 'py_aa_spi_write', 'py_aa_status_string', 'py_aa_target_power', 'py_aa_unique_id', 'py_aa_version', 'py_version']`

ctypes import `dir(api)` gives me:

`['_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_flags_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name']`

I'm not sure what to try next.  I'm fine working with my stuff in Python 2.7, but I'd really like to offer Python 3 compatibility.

Comment: Just rename it to `aardvark.pyd`. Python extension modules are native shared libraries, but on Windows the extension is changed to .pyd. Of course it needs to be compiled against and only works with a particular minor version of CPython (e.g. 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, etc).

Comment: Relative path works fine in Python 2.7 with rename .dll -> .pyd.  Still have errors in Python 3.4.  Looking deeper into the API docs provided by Total Phase, it is referencing building this against Python 2.5.  Does that mean Python 3 support is just not really possible with the existing DLLs?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't explicitly link with python25.dll, so `load_dynamic` doesn't raise the usual `ImportError` for conflicting versions. Probably it's dynamically linking to the 2.x C API and exports the `initaardvark` function that 2.x `load_dynamic` calls to initialize the module. 3.x instead looks for `PyInit_aardvark`.

Comment: @Joe Have you been able to resolve the issue for python 3.x? Did you end up just using python 2.7?

Comment: I completely gave up on the Ardvark.  Hobbyist tools worked better than professional ones for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with importing an external library on Python 3.6 through `importlib`. The official docs give this recipe to import a source file directly:

```py
import importlib.util
import sys

# For illustrative purposes.
import tokenize
file_path = tokenize.__file__
module_name = tokenize.__name__

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
# Optional; only necessary if you want to be able to import the module
# by name later.
sys.modules[module_name] = module
```

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly)

I adapted this to:

```py
import importlib.util

def load_dynamic(module, path):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module, path)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    return mod
```

You should then be able to do something like this on Python 3:

```py
load_dynamic('aardvark', os.path.join(cur_path, 'ext', 'win32', 'aardvark.dll'))
```